# Calling java script function automatically using form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a java script function that i need to call over and over again in order to test it, so i wrote a form that allows me to call the function, i have to do this manually and need a way to call this function without user input. all that needs to go to the upload file is a number and some text, (ex 1     Thank you)

```
<script src="yo.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<body>
<form action="uploadFile" method="post"> 
  <input type="text" name="filename" >  
  <input type="text" name="fileData">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can hire someone to do work for you. If you're into learning than that's a different story but from you post it seems like you're just looking for someone to solve the problem for you when you've taken no initiative yourself. Take that somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Runs every second:

```
setInterval(function () {uploadFile('some text', 'some number')}, 1000);
```